# How do I display a list of items from a Bean onto a JSF webpage?

Tags: loops, jsf, jsf-2, collections, iteration

I'm new to JSF and in the process of learning im building an online book store application.

I have 1 class and 1 bean: `Book.java` and `BookCatelogBean.java`. The Book class has 3 properties: `id`, `title`, and `author` with it's corresponding getters and setters. The `BookCatelogBean` contains an `ArrayList<Book>` where I populate it with `Books` (in future I will connect it to a database).

I have two pages: `index.xhtml` and `book.xhtml`. I want to display the list of book titles on `index.xhtml` each formatted as a REST link and their ID to `book.xhtml`, like so: `<h:link outcome="book?id=#{bookCatelogBean.id}" value="#{bookCatelogBean.title}" />`

I know how to use `BookCatelogBean` to display 1 `book` but I want to display all of them? I have an idea to call a method from `BookCatelogBean` called `getAllBooks()` that returns each of the books titles but how would I return each one of them to index.xhtml as a JavaserverFace link instead of a string?

Thanks

Here is my code:

**Book.java**

```
package bookshop;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Book implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public Book(int id, String title, String author){
        this.title = title;
        this.id = id;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

**BookCatelogBean.java**

```
package bookshop;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BookCatelogBean implements Serializable {
    private int currentItem = 0;

    private ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(Arrays.asList(
            new Book(1, "Theory of Money and Credit", "Ludwig von Mises"),
            new Book(2, "Man, Economy and State", "Murry Rothbard"),
            new Book(3, "Real Time Relationships", "Stefan Molyneux")));

    public String getTitle(){
        return books.get(currentItem).getTitle();
    }

    public int getId(){
        return books.get(currentItem).getId();
    }

    public String getAuthor(){
        return books.get(currentItem).getAuthor();
    }

}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>BookShop</title>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:link outcome="book?id=#{bookCatelogBean.id}" value="#{bookCatelogBean.title}" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is a c:forEach what I need here?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

JSF2 offers two iterating components out the box: [`<ui:repeat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) and [`<h:dataTable>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html). The former renders nothing to the response (so you have 100% control over the final HTML output), while the latter renders a HTML `<table>` to the response and requires a [`<h:column>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/column.html) to represent a column of `<td>`s. Both components can take among others a `List<E>` as value.

So, you can just have your managed bean like follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BookCatalog implements Serializable {

    private List<Book> books;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        books.add(new Book(1, "Theory of Money and Credit", "Ludwig von Mises"));
        books.add(new Book(2, "Man, Economy and State", "Murry Rothbard"));
        books.add(new Book(3, "Real Time Relationships", "Stefan Molyneux"));
    }

    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

}
```

And you can use `<ui:repeat>` to generate for example an `<ul><li>`:

```html
<ul>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bookCatalog.books}" var="book">
        <li>
            <h:link value="#{book.title}" outcome="book">
                <f:param name="id" value="#{book.id}" />
            </h:link>
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

*(note that the `var` attribute basically exposes the currently iterated item by exactly the given name in the EL scope within the component)*

And here's how to use a `<h:dataTable>` instead:

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{bookCatalog.books}" var="book">
    <h:column>
        <h:link value="#{book.title}" outcome="book">
            <f:param name="id" value="#{book.id}" />
        </h:link>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

As to the JSTL `<c:forEach>`, that's also quite possible, but you should keep in mind that JSTL tags have a different lifecycle than JSF components. Long story short: [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/)
- [How and when should I load the model from database for h:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765853/when-should-i-load-the-collection-from-database-for-hdatatable/)
- [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/creating-master-detail-pages-for-entities-how-to-link-them-and-which-bean-scope)

Comment: I tried out the above code and got an apparently empty list. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: I withdraw the above question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use PrimeFaces library

Link: [PrimeFaces datatable](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml)