# DataTable .rowIndex always returns 0

Tags: jsf, datatable, jsf-2.2

What am I not doing right?

```
@Named("utilityController")
@RequestScoped
public class UtilityController {
    public DataModel<Result> getResultSample() {
        Result[] resultSample = new Result[11];
        //Populate the array
        return new ArrayDataModel<>(resultSample);
    }
}
```

In The JSF:

```
<h:dataTable id="sampleResult" value="#{utilityController.resultSample}" var="item" styleClass="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed" >
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">SN</f:facet>
        #{utilityController.resultSample.rowIndex}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Subject</f:facet>
        #{item.subject.name}
    </h:column>
    ....
</h:dataTable>
```

[image]

The rowIndex always returns 0 as can be seen above. Please can some help me pin point what I am doing wrongly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What am I not doing right?*

Creating the model in a getter method. Never do that. All getter methods should look like this:

```
public DataModel<Result> getResultSample() {
    return resultSample;
}
```

The getter method is invoked on every iteration round. You're basically clearing out the model from the previous iteration round and returning a brand new one, with all state (such as current row index) reset to default value.

Move that job to bean's `@PostConstruct` method.

```
private DataModel<Result> resultSample;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Result[] results = new Result[11];
    // ...
    resultSample = new ArrayDataModel<Result>(results);
}

public DataModel<Result> getResultSample() {
    return resultSample;
}
```

As to your concrete functional requirement, you can also just reference [`UIData#getRowIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getRowIndex--) without wrapping the value in a `DataModel`.

```
public Result[] getResults() { // Consider List<Result> instead.
    return results;
}
```

```html
<h:dataTable binding="#{table}" value="#{bean.results}" var="result">
    <h:column>#{table.rowIndex + 1}</h:column>
    <h:column>#{result.subject.name}</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Note that I incremented it with 1 as it's 0-based while humans expect an 1-based index.

#### See also:

- [How and when should I load the model from database for h:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765853/when-should-i-load-the-collection-from-database-for-hdatatable)
- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)
- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, your second suggestion seems like a perfect one, I looking the link and will revert shortly

Comment: WoooW this is working perfectly well with the binding approach. But please @BalusC where is the table object coming from? I did not define it any where yet it has the rowIndex and what other attributes could it possibly have?

Comment: Click the `UIData` link in my answer for the javadoc. All `getXxx()` methods are also available in EL this way. I also added a third "see also" link explaining the `binding` attribute.

Comment: Thanks once more @BalusC those links have been very useful