# javax.el.ELException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.add

Tags: java, list, jsf, el

On Wildfly 9 (JSF 2.2, EL 3.0) I have two nested `<ui:repeat>` tags and want to use the var attribute of the outer one as method argument for the inner:

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.getEntries()}" var="entry">
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.getPosts(entry)}" var="post">
        <p id="text">#{post.text}</p>
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

`bean.getEntries()` returns `List<Entry>` and `bean.getPosts(Entry entry)` returns `List<Post>` as one would expect.

But instead of some `<p>` tags filled with posts I get an exception:

```
11:24:26,574 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-2) Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /WEB-INF/templates/diary.xhtml @14,73 value="#{sessionBean.getPublicPosts(elEntry)}": java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getValue(UIRepeat.java:279)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:255)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:523)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:577)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1110)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:104)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:621)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1110)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:655)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:312)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:136)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
at org.bollin.diary.util.SessionBean.getPublicPosts(SessionBean.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)
... 57 more

11:24:26,580 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /diary/index.jsf: javax.servlet.ServletException
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:667)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
at org.bollin.diary.util.SessionBean.getPublicPosts(SessionBean.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:136)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getValue(UIRepeat.java:279)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:255)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:523)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:577)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1110)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:104)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:621)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1110)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:655)
... 27 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at org.bollin.diary.util.SessionBean.getPublicPosts(SessionBean.java:124)
```

The `List` implementation being used in line 124 of `SessionBean` class, inside the `getPublicPosts()` method, doesn't support calling the `add()` method.

That can happen when it's an unmodifiable list such as ones returned by [`Collections#unmodifiableList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) and [`Arrays#asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-).

Wrap it in a modifiable list before modifying it.

```
modifiableList = new ArrayList<>(unmodifiableList);
```

Note that this problem is not strictly related to JSF nor EL, it's just basic Java. You can reproduce exactly the same problem using a simple Java application class with a `main()` method. In future questions it's wise to first do that in order to exclude JSF/EL from being the probable cause.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this signals another design problem: performing business logic in a Javabean getter method. This is performance wise a really bad idea as it's in this specific construct invoked during every iteration round. Move the business logic into a method which is called only once in the desired scope, such as a `@PostConstruct` annotated method. See also [How and when should I load the model from database for h:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765853/when-should-i-load-the-collection-from-database-for-hdatatable/).