# p:dataTable sortBy and filterBy bringing results back to 0 when using bean that was set as an attribute to an xhtml page from a servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, primefaces, datatable

So I have a servlet that creates a new bean, calls a function on that bean with a List that is passed into it that makes a new List in that bean and returns that list.

I then set that bean as an attribute and use it in the next .xhtml page for a Primefaces datatable.

This works fine, but if I try sorting, filtering, or going to the next page of that table, the table becomes empty.

I've been googling this problem for a while now and can't figure out what is going on. Anyone wanna help?

Primefaces 5.2
JSF 2.0.11 
WebLogic 10.3.6 
Java 1.6

**Servlet:**

```
    FileTrackerBean bean = new FileTrackerBean();
    bean.occupyList(rows, env);     
    request.setAttribute("bean", bean);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("testFileTracker.xhtml").forward(request, response);
```

**Bean:**

```
private List<File> fileArrayList;

public List<File> getFileList() {
     if(fileArrayList == null){
         return null;
     }else{
        return fileArrayList;
     }

}

public void occupyList(List<Row> rows, String env) {
    for(int x = 0; x < rows.size(); x++){
        addToList(rows.get(x), x, env);
    }
}

public void addToList(Row row, int index, String env){
    File temp = new File(row.getFileName(), row.getStatus(), row.getUserID(), row.getProducerPath(), row.getConsumerPath(),
            row.getFileSize(), row.getLastModified(), row.getwfidNum(), env);
    fileArrayList.add(temp);
}

public File(String fileName, String status, String userID, String producerPath, String consumerPath,
            String fileSize, String lastModified, String wfidNum, String env){
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.status = status;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.producerPath = producerPath;
        this.consumerPath = consumerPath;
        this.fileSize = fileSize;
        this.lastModified = lastModified;
        this.wfidNum = wfidNum;
        this.env = env;
    }
```

**.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  
  xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
  >
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table.css"  />
    <script src="js\resultsJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body onload="setUp(${displayNum})">

    <h1>
        <a href="HomePage.jsp">Home</a> - <a href="FileTracker.jsp">File Tracker</a><br/>
    </h1>
      <h:form>
        <p:dataTable value="#{bean.fileList}" var="f"
            tableStyle="table-layout: auto"
            paginator="true"
            rows="20"
            styleClass="table"
            headerClass="header"
            columnClasses="table"
            rowClasses="table-odd-row,table-even-row"
            resizableColumns="true"
            paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="20, 50, 100" lazy="true">
        >

        <p:column headerText="Original File Name" sortBy="#{f.fileName}" filterBy="#{f.fileName}">
            <h:outputText value="#{f.fileName}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Status" sortBy="#{f.status}" filterBy="#{f.status}">
            <button class="status" type="button" onclick="goToWFID('#{f.wfidNum}','#{f.env}', '#{f.status}', '#{f.fileName}') value='#{f.status}'">#{f.status}</button>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="User ID" sortBy="#{f.userID}" filterBy="#{f.userID}">
            <h:outputText value="#{f.userID}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Producer Mailbox Path" sortBy="#{f.producerPath}" filterBy="#{f.producerPath}">
            <h:outputText value="#{f.producerPath}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Consumer Mailbox Path" sortBy="#{f.consumerPath}" filterBy="#{f.consumerPath}">
            <h:outputText value="#{f.consumerPath}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="File Size (bytes)" sortBy="#{f.fileSize}" filterBy="#{f.fileSize}">
            <h:outputText value="#{f.fileSize}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Last Modified" sortBy="#{f.lastModified}" filterBy="#{f.lastModified}">
            <h:outputText value="#{f.lastModified}"/>
        </p:column>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            #{fn:length(bean.fileList)}
            <h:outputText value="Results"/>
        </f:facet>

        </p:dataTable>
      </h:form>
            <h1>
    <a href="FileTracker.jsp">Try again?</a>
</h1>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which is the scope of the backing bean containing the list?

Comment: @lametaweb it is sessionscoped

Comment: I see `fileList` in the table, where is  it defined?

Comment: @lametaweb I don't actually have a variable called fileList. I'm pretty sure when I call fileList in the table, it calls getFileList(). But when I put in a system.out.println in it, nothing comes out.

Comment: That servlet doesn't make any sense. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765853/when-should-i-load-the-collection-from-database-for-hdatatable

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a backing bean in request scope, so the scope of the backing bean will not be session. You should put only the parameters of the occupyList method, `rows` and `env`, in the request scope, instead of the all backing bean. Then in the page you call a viewAction method, `yourBackingBean.updateModel()`, to read those parameters and call the `occupyList` method, so initializing the Model, `yourBackingBean.fileArrayList`:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{yourBackingBean.updateModel()}"></f:viewAction>
</f:metadata>
```

In `updateModel` you read the parameters `rows` and `env` and call the `occupyList` method. If `env` is a framework object accesible from the backing bean you should pass only the `rows` value.

Comment: The servlet itself is not request scoped. OP is just manually creating and putting the bean in the request scope.