# Can't filtering Primefaces datatable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, filter, datatable

I have a dataTable with dynamic Columns.

So I use primefaces 5.3 and jsf 2.2

Here is code :

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:dataTable var="etudiant" widgetVar="etdTable" paginator="true" rows="10"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" value="#{etudiantController.etudiants}"
    lazy="false" emptyMessage="Aucune etudiant trouvé"
    filteredValue="#{etudiantController.filteredEtudiants}">

       <p:column filterBy="#{etudiant.nomEtudiant}" filterMatchMode="exact">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Nom" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{etudiant.nomEtudiant}" />
      </p:column>
      [...]
```

Bean :

```
private List<Etudiant> etudiants;
private List<Etudiant> filteredEtudiants;

public List<Etudiant> getEtudiants() {
    return etudiantService.getAllEtudiants();
}

public List<Etudiant> getFilteredEtudiants() {
    return this.filteredEtudiants;
}

public void setFilteredEtudiants(List<Etudiant> filteredEtudiants) {
    this.filteredEtudiants = filteredEtudiants;
}
```

getAllEtudiants() load all students.

Exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.filter(FilterFeature.java:150)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.encode(FilterFeature.java:117)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:78)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) [...]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.startCDATA(HtmlResponseWriter.java:681) at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.startCDATA(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:179)[...]
```

something is wrong here??

Comment: I think that is the problem, or at least, it must be solved. A getter in jsf can be called 100 times just to show the page once. So you can never call the db in a getter.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765853/how-and-when-should-i-load-the-model-from-database-for-hdatatable

Comment: I loaded it on PostConstruct but stil not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm ot sure but did you try to inicialize the list?

try this:

```
private List<Etudiant> filteredEtudiants = new ArrayList<>();
```