# I can't use varStatus value to get index in p:repeat

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I My xhtml code is this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
     xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <p:column headerText="Student">
              <p:repeat value="#{student.convertList()}" var="item" varStatus="index">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.nameStudent}" id="#{index}" />
               </p:repeat>
            </p:column>
```

The method `student.converList()` is used because my Students are in a Set so I need to convert set in List:

```
public List<Student> convertList() {    
        return new ArrayList<Autori>(this.setStudent);
    }
```

it gives me:

Empty id attribute is not allowed

Anyone can help me?

Comment: So this fails too? `<h:outputText value="#{index}"/>` And if you can't use it, do you get an error or WW3 or? And don't do any work in getters...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765853/how-and-when-should-i-load-the-model-from-database-for-hdatatable

Comment: Try my comment... Does that work... it will, so you **can** use the varStatus for an index...

Comment: yes it gives me " Empty id attribute is not allowed"

Comment: Tried the output text from my initial comment? And a searhengine already gives you the answer: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=jsf+Empty+id+attribute+is+not+allowed+repeat